# Serialize parameters for remote procedure call

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

I want to design a RPC scenario.

1. The client call is serialized using DataContractJsonSerializer.
2. The serialized request is passed to service.
3. Service deserializes the request and use it to invoke the native method.
4. Service returns the result as serialized response.
5. Client deserialize the response

Here I found a problem with DataContractJsonSerializer. When serializing, List is converted to object[]. But after deserializing, object[] will not be transformed back to List.

As this is a generic RPC scenario, method may vary both in the number and type. I can not make a cast one by one.

I wonder if there is a better resolution/framework for such RPC implementation.

Comment: Yes there are. You should rarely, if ever, have to do serialisation stuff yourself. WCF should handle this for you. Or ServiceStack, or gRPC, or pretty much any other framework. I would recommend gRPC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.0